# Adding new property to every object of array using spread operator does not work

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with binary Files like this

`[{item: File},{item: File},{item: File}]`

and i need to add new key/value to every obj. I tried doing it with mapping an array and concatenating new property 'description' with existing 'name':

`arr.map((el) => ({ ...el, description: '' }))`

so it should look like this:

`[{item: File, description: ''},{item: File, description: ''},{item: File, description: ''}]`.

But when i try to do this, it only returns a description without name:

[image: pic]

Comment: Are you sure your original objects have `name` properties to begin with? What you have showed should work. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: My bad. Initially i tried to add description to object with binary File. Edited it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe you forgot to assign 'map'

returned value to your object. lets do it:

```
let arr = [{name: '1'},{name: '2'},{name: '3'}]
arr = arr.map( item => ({ ...item, description:'' }) )
console.log(arr)
```

result is :

```
0: {name: "1", description: ""}
1: {name: "2", description: ""}
2: {name: "3", description: ""}
```

Comment: Well, the image shows that the object has a `description` property...